# tabledata get id value from checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to display data using Datatable, whenever I try to get the id value from checkbox I get `undefined`.

Datatable code

```
   $(function () {
        $('#reviews_data').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: url,
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id', render: function (id) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox_minimal" data-id="'+id+'"> ';
                }
                },
                {data: 'status', render: function (status,data,rowData) {
                    return  ' <div class="checkbox">\n' +
                        '<input id="exampleCheckboxSwitch" type="checkbox" data-id="'+rowData.id+'">\n' +
                        '<label for="exampleCheckboxSwitch"></label>\n' +
                        '</div>';
                }},
                {
                    data: 'status', render: function (data, data1, row, meta) {
                    return data + ' <br>' + row.created_at;
                }, "bUseRendered": false
                },
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            ]
        });
    });
```

this issue with this one

```
{data: 'status', render: function (status,data,rowData) {
                    return  ' <div class="checkbox">\n' +
                        '<input id="exampleCheckboxSwitch" type="checkbox" data-id="'+rowData.id+'">\n' +
                        '<label for="exampleCheckboxSwitch"></label>\n' +
                        '</div>';
                }},
```

as you see in the code I'm trying to get the id from

```
data-id="'+rowData.id+'"
```

using this Jquery code

```
   $(document).change('.checkbox',function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        console.log(id);

    });
```

I tried to use value instead of data-id but did work either

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental mistake here. You cannot use an event delegation like this.

```
$(document).change('.checkbox',function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Try this way:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function () {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: nice  I didn't know that on support change as well , but why $(document).change  didn't work ??